# I want to run a method/access a variable from a JS file which I have created

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created a JS file "demoscript.js", I have uploaded it in the static resource with the name "demoscript", "public" & "type - text/javascript".

```
let fixedval= "32456789";
function create(){
    console.log("called create");
}
```

I have also created an LWC component and imported it like this in the makepayment.js-

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import demoscript from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/demoscript';
export default class PagePayment extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
            Promise.all([
                loadScript(this,demoscript,'demoscript.js')
            ])
            .then(()=>{
                console.log('success');
                this.demoscriptInitialize();
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log("error " +JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }

    demoscriptInitialize(){
        const temp = window.fixedval;
        console.log('temp'+temp);
    }
}
```

but the console is printing "temp undefined" , my question is how do I access fixedval. I have tried-
1.Export the fixedval in the demoscript.js
2.I have tried to assign it using window.fixedval

I am also getting the following error in the console -"Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' "

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your JS file using this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/js_third_party_library

1. Import the static resource.
   `import resourceName from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/resourceName';`
2. Import methods from the platformResourceLoader module.
   `import { loadStyle, loadScript } from                     'lightning/platformResourceLoader';`
3. Use this method to import your JS file `loadScript(self, fileUrl): Promise`